# itextsharp: disable clipboard for pdf

Tags: vb.net, itext

I have a function that receives a PDF file from the desktop. What I want is that, before saving the PDF, deactivate the clipboard so that they cannot copy the text or images of the document.

My code:

```
Dim NombreArchivo As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName) ' obtiene nombre archivo

Dim docsubido As New Document()
Dim SaveLocation As String = Server.MapPath("Pdf") & "\" & NombreArchivo ' obtiene ruta donde se guardara
If Not File1.PostedFile Is Nothing And File1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0 Then
    Try

        File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation)

        Response.Write("El archivo ha sido cargado.")
    Catch Exc As Exception
        Response.Write("Error: " & Exc.Message)
    End Try
Else
    Response.Write("Seleccione un archivo para cargar.")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) The web server has no control of the client, so you cannot do that. 2) If the user can see the file on the screen, they can screen-grab it to get the images, and use OCR on the screen-grab to get the text.

Comment: What you probably mean is that you want to put content into the pdf in a way that pdf viewers commonly don't support copying and pasting it from the file. This is entirely different from 'deactivating the clipboard' which is not achievable from the web server as @Andrew already mentioned. This also is not explicitly supported by itext high level apis but it is possible to do using itext low level apis. Obviously, though, you have a moving target, what is not supported for copy and paste today may be supported in tomorrow's pdf viewer version.

Comment: Exactly, my intention is to be able to manipulate the pdf so that the content can not be copied @mkl

Comment: Just to make sure: for which iText version are you looking for a solution of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this was the solution to be able to disable the property of copying and pasting of a PDF only the option to print

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper
Private Sub Submit1_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Submit1.ServerClick
            Dim NombrePdfEntrada As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName) ' obtiene nombre archivo

            Dim SaveLocation As String = Server.MapPath("Pdf") & "\" & NombrePdfEntrada ' obtiene ruta donde se guardara
            If Not File1.PostedFile Is Nothing And File1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0 Then
                Try
                    File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation)
                    Dim ArchivoCargado As New PdfReader(SaveLocation)
                    Dim rutasalida As New FileStream(Server.MapPath("Pdf") & "\Nuevo" & NombrePdfEntrada, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
                    Dim stampArchivoOutput As New PdfStamper(ArchivoCargado, rutasalida)
                    Dim passdue As String = ""
                    Dim arraydueño() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passdue)
                    Dim passinv As String = ""
                    Dim arrayinvitado() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passinv)
                    stampArchivoOutput.SetEncryption(False, passdue, passinv, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING)
                    stampArchivoOutput.Close()
                    ArchivoCargado.Close()
                    Response.Write("El archivo ha sido cargado.")
                Catch Exc As Exception
                    Response.Write("Error: " & Exc.Message & Exc.HelpLink
                                   )
                End Try
            Else
                Response.Write("Seleccione un archivo para cargar.")
            End If

        End Sub
    End Class
```